# Should a gradle root project include a build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

When looking at the gradle documentation, the example it gives for multi-project builds states:

> Note that the root project does not have a Gradle build file, only a settings file that defines the subprojects to include.

The thing I am wondering is whether or not a root project not having a build file would be considered best practices or if the documentation is vague in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a need for it, you could yes! For example, I have a few check-environment tasks run at root before running any multi-modules.

If you don't think you need it though, I'm fairly sure you can do without it!

Answer (score 0):

It is commonly used to load project-wide plugins, so one probably should include it.
And it is rather the other way around - one does not need any of the `subprojects`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you structured your project. If you have subprojects and need to make some common function, then use build.gradle to define a task/config/dependencies.  Example, use to create a jar for the entire project.